# Conditional writing to data table columns in R

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to write to a column in a data table with conditionals, like so:

```
dt[colour == "blue"][ , col1 := blue_func(size)]
dt[colour == "red"][ , col1 := red_func(size)]
```

When I run this in R, it executes, but when I later call the column `dt$col1` it returns `NULL`.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Why not just `dt[colour == "blue" , col1 := blue_func(size)]` and `dt[colour == "red", col1 := red_func(size)]` ?

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? *facepalm* Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is because you are assigning to a new, temporary `data.table` which is a subset of `dt`, not `dt` itself. As in:

```
dt <- data.table(id=1:2,colour=c("blue","red"))
dt

#   id colour
#1:  1   blue
#2:  2    red

dt[colour=="blue"]

#   id colour
#1:  1   blue

dt[colour=="blue"][, col1 := nchar(colour)]
dt

#   id colour
#1:  1   blue
#2:  2    red
```

You can see the assignment is working if you `print` the temporary object:

```
print(dt[colour=="blue"][, col1 := nchar(colour)])

#   id colour col1
#1:  1   blue    4
```

As @DavidArenburg notes, you need to do it all in one fell swoop if you want the changes to be registered to `dt`:

```
dt[colour == "blue", col1 := nchar(colour)]
dt

#   id colour col1
#1:  1   blue    4
#2:  2    red   NA
```